# How to test and debug Cocoa App on different version of OSx using same Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, testing, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I made an Application using my Mac with Yosemite. On Completion of that I archived it and Then distribute to few friends, one of them have Mavericks. I faced some issues on that Mavericks System. With the occurrence of this thing, following queries raised in my mind,

- Can I check my application on different OSX version, without running it actually on different MACs?
- Can I also debug my application with different OSX Versions, using a system having single Osx?

In Nutshell, I want to know, is it Possible to test Cocoa application with multiple versions? something similar like iOS development where I can run app on different iOS versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to suggest to buy a copy of `VMWare` or `Parallels` to install older OS X versions in a virtual machine.

You can download older versions of OS X from https://developer.apple.com or buy them online via http://store.apple.com/ca/help/downloadable_software#MacOSX

This works pretty well and saves you from the trouble of making a dual boot machine. Which is often not even possible because recent hardware may only work with Yosemite.